# ExtJS4 - Grid Store pageSize

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to make the pageSize of the store be limited to 1. I have 10 items in the grid and while the paging mechanism is correct showing 1 of 10, 2 of 10 etc, the grid still displays all 10 items. I've also tried returning in the json the "total" property to 1 but this still doesn't work. Any ideas?

The example in the documentation isn't very helpful either as it shows the source code but the live preview is empty.

```
        var photos = new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'Photos',
            autoLoad: true,
            pageSize: 1
        });

        var photosGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id: 'PhotoGrid',
            store: photos,
            columns: [
                       { text: "Filename", width: 200, dataIndex: 'filename' }
                    ],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: photos,
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            }],
            region: 'center',
            border: 0,
            overCls: 'row-pointer'
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei, well your problem is you are probably returning all 10 items in your json, The paging backed you have to implement yourself, all the paging is doing is calling a load on the store with specific parameters like the limit of the page and the page start index. You have to use these parameters on the backend to send one item at a time. Chers mate.

**EDIT**

```
//this is the model we will be using in the store
Ext.define('Page', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',    type: 'int'},
    ]
});

var data = null;
var store = null;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){
        data = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'Page',
            pageSize: 1,
            data : data,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                  type: 'json',
                  root: 'pages'//this has to be as the root from your json
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: thats not cool. what I wanted was to be able to grab a document and split up that document into pages and save them as an image then using the grid to navigate these images one at a time. any idea on how to use this with a store? It's like the store needs to be in memory and you pull one image at a time from this repository.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the memory proxy, I've personaly haven't used it but it doesn't seem to complicated.. you just keep your data in a variable and the store uses the proxy to get data from there. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory

Comment: I think even with a memory store, you will have the same problem with pageSize. I'm not sure yet on how to store json in memory and only get one at a time. The memory store will contain all the items, but if you put a limit or page size on the store, you would only one to store 1 item in the json at a time so defeats the purpose. Will have to think of a different approach as I can't see this working. Cheers.

Comment: you missundestood me, load all the pages by an ajax request into an array of data, and then another store with pageSize 1 that uses a memory proxy will load the data from the local array, one by one, i;ll edit my answer with what i am thinking..

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of query in your script formatting the json.
When you use extjs with pageSize, it sends queries with parameters (`page` & `limit`, i remember).
In your server side script, you have to check if they exist, and if so, change your query to add a `limit` clause (or equivalent in other databases).